# how to get checkbox status in from MVC view using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

There is a checkbox created by html helper in MVC view:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("Choice", false)%>
```

Then Want to get the checking status of this this checkbox in js using jquery, how to write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#Choice').is(':checked')) {
  //is checked
} else {
  //is not checked
}
```

or you might even be able to do

```
if($('#Choice:checked')) {
  //is checked
} else {
  //is not checked
}
```

Comment: Ouch!I've been bitten by this. The value seems to be either true for checked, or "undefined" for false.
OK for simple logic as above, but I had a smidgen more logic to process, with the expectation I'd get a false.